# Sort Tuples Python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples in my Blender python code

```
scores=[(1489,"Sean"), (2850,"Bob"), (276,"Crap Player"), (78495, "Great Player"), (8473, "Damian"), (4860, "Andy"), (0, "Stephen")]
```

I'm trying to sort them by their score by using this

```
sorted(scores, key=lambda score: score[0], reverse=True)
```

but this is not working. I have no idea why. Any tips?

I've considered maybe a better implementation is to create a new `Score` class with fields `name` and `score`

**EDIT:**

Thanks guys for the fast reply

it was giving me no errors with the `sorted` method but was not  sorting.
I used the `sort()` and it works.

I think python is just a little weird in Blender maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine: http://codepad.org/6AT3rCw3

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: You probably did not assign the result of sorted to a variable but what you need is actually sort

Comment: I think the title is misleading. When I saw it I though the OP would want to know how to sort a tuple, not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just do:

```
print sorted(scores, reverse=True)
[(78495, 'Great Player'), (8473, 'Damian'), (4860, 'Andy'), (2850, 'Bob'), (1489, 'Sean'), (276, 'Crap Player'), (0, 'Stephen')]
```

you can use `scores.sort(reverse=True)` if you want to sort in place, and by the way the sort function in case of list of tuple by default sort by first item , second item ..

Comment: This will also sort players with identical scores alphabetically, which might be desirable.

Comment: @RobertHensing Is there a way to get `sorted` to *not* sort by the 2nd key (i.e player names)? Docs say that `sorted` is *guaranteed* to be stable, so it should be preserving the original order when the 1ary keys being compared are equal, but it doesn't.

Comment: In that case, you actually have to use the `key` function explicitly. For example: `sorted(scores, reverse=True, key=lambda s: s[0])`

Comment: I have three parameters to sort 2 strings and numerical value - what should I do, write function that produces concatenated string of some sort  and then compare these strings????

Answer (score 10):

`sorted()` returns the sorted sequence. If you want to sort a list in place then use `list.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
scores.sort(reverse=True)
>>> print scores
[(78495, 'Great Player'), (8473, 'Damian'), (4860, 'Andy'), (2850, 'Bob'), (1489, 'Sean'), (276, 'Crap Player'), (0, 'Stephen')]
```